# SQL - WHERE statement with text added to value from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to copy data from an old database to a newer one. 
Both of these databases have a user setup table with the primary key of `"USER ID"`.

The problem is, in the old database the users didn't have the domain in the name, but in the new one they have.

Example:

```
Primary Key old DB: USER1  
Primary Key new DB: DOMAIN\USER1
```

This prevents a standard WHERE clause to update the correct user because it can't find it due to the domain being added.

My code:

```
'FROM [' + @src_DB + '].dbo.[' + @src_table + '] as src ' 
'WHERE [' + @dest_DB + '].dbo.[' + @dest_table + '].[User ID] = ' + @domain_name + 'src.[User ID]'
```

printing the result:

```
WHERE [Destination_DB].dbo.[Destination_Table].[User ID] = DOMAIN\src.[User ID]
```

The problem is it doesn't add the DOMAIN to the value but rather to the statement...

How can I add the Domain to the actual value of `src.[User ID]`?

Comment: This may not apply to your use case, but manually building a `WHERE` clause in the context of application logic (which interacts with the outside world) is risky, because you could get SQL injected.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not worried about that because it is a one-time script to move data between two databases in a local environment

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a dot missing, and you should use `QUOTENAME`

```
'WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(destination_table) + '.[User ID] = ' + QUOTENAME(@domain) + '.' + QUOTENAME(source_table) + '.[User ID]'
```

Whenever you create a SQL statement dynamically it's a good idea to print it out, copy it into a new query window and check for syntax errors...

### UPDATE You: *Yes, both databases are in the same server*

An object can be (fully) specified with

```
ServerName.DatabaseName.Schema.ObjectName
```

A table's column would add one more `.ColumnName`

When both objects live on the same server you can let the first part away.

Objects of the same database let this part away.

Objects of the default schema might be called with the `ObjectName` alone.

But if you state a `DatabaseName` **you must also state a `SchemaName`!**

Use `QUOTENAME()` to add the brackets and add just the dots via string concatenation (or use `CONCAT()`-function).

### UPDATE 2 Did I get this wrong completely?

After you comment I think I understand it now: You want to compare the **values** of both `[USER ID]` columns, but the new is `DOMAIN\MyUserId` while the older was just `MyUserId`.

You have two approaches

- Add the `Domain\` as string **to the value of `[User ID]`**
- Use `SUBSTRING([User ID],CHARINDEX('\',[UserID])+1,1000)` to cut the newer value down to the naked value of `[User ID]`

For the first something like this

```
'WHERE [' + @dest_DB + '].dbo.[' + @dest_table + '].[User ID] = ''' + @domain_name + ''' + src.[User ID]'
```

The second is quite clumsy with dynamically created SQL...

Comment: I have provided the print result in the OP and reformed the code a bit to better understand my issue (hopefully)

Comment: @BlackOutDev In your edit `+ @domain_name + 'src.[User ID]` I think there is still a dot missing (before `src`)...

Comment: @BlackOutDev It was good, to print out the created statement. For sure the Backslash is not correct here: `DOMAIN\src.[User ID]`

Comment: With the dot it says:
WHERE [...].[User ID] = DOMAIN\.src.[User ID]

Comment: And the error i get is:
Incorrect syntax near '\.'.

Comment: @BlackOutDev You must remove the Backslash. Either using `REPLACE()` or avoid it to be part of the string...

Comment: But the user ID in the destination table is "DOMAIN\User1" so how do i prevent adding the backslash and still finding this value?

Comment: @BlackOutDev Both databases live in the same SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, both databases are in the same server.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand it correctly. My issue is not to access the data correctly. My issue is that i have 2 tables with the same columns and the same primary key. Both of these tables have the same amount of lines (1 line for each user). Now i want to copy the values from table B to table A for the same user, but the data for "USER ID" (primary key) changed between those tables. 

If i leave the "DOMAIN\" out, the basic statement would be "WHERE DOMAIN\User1 = User1"... which doesn't work because it can't find the user